# How can I access to number of blocker and critical issues for each sonarqube analysis?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I saw in the sonar time machine that it was possible to see for each analysis the number of blocker and critical issues, but I didn't find where these metrics are stocked and how to retrieve them one by one externally with a Java program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the web service api/timemachine/index. It is documented within the application, for example at https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/timemachine/index

The metrics for having numbers of issues are `violations` (total number, whatever the severity), `blocker_violations`, `critical_violations`, `major_violations`, `minor_violations` and `info_violations`.

Example: https://sonarqube.com/api/timemachine/index?resource=org.fitnesse:fitnesse&metrics=blocker_violations,critical_violations

Comment: Thank you, it works, but is there any way to retrieve the details for each issue in each analysis? For example, with an id or something like this.

Comment: No it's not possible. What's your use-case ?

Comment: I want to know how many issues have been solved and this is why I need the time machine. I want the detail because the time machine doesn't show which issue have been solved so, for example, if someone solves an issue, but at the same time create a new, the number of issues doesn't show it.